# How to find integral $\int e^{-2x} /x\,dx\,$?

Tags: probability, integration, definite-integrals, covariance

How to find integral $\int e^{-2x} /x\,dx\,$?

The question I am trying to answer is:
If X, Y are random variables with joint pdf
$f(x,y)=2e^{-2x} /x$ for $0\lt y \leq x$ what's the Covariance of X and Y? I get that the $cov(X,Y) = E(X*Y)-EX*EY$ and the E(X*Y) and EX are easy to get, but for the EY, I am first margining y by

$\int^\infty_y 2e^{-2x} /x dx$

But how in the world do you evaluate that integral? The complexity in solutions (which involve the exponential integral: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral)
that I've found suggest to me that I did not get the up correctly? If that looks correct, then how do you evaluate the integral?

Comment: This is (up to a constant) the elliptic integral $\text{Ei}(-x)$.

Comment: The very Wikipedia article you cited tells you how to evaluate the function $\operatorname{Ei}(x)$ numerically and for some exact values as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not evaluate that integral. $EY=\int_0^{\infty} y\int_y^{\infty} 2e^{-2x}/x dx$. Interchange the integrals to get $EY=\int_0^{\infty}(\int_0^{x} ydy)2e^{-2x}/x dx$. This becomes $\int_0^{\infty} xe^{-2x}dx$ and you can evaluate this by a simple integration by parts.